# PHP Regex -  /i caseless not working and weird empty array elements

Tags: php, regex

Source texts (7):

1. give 4 cars
2. ga 5 cars
3. GA 5 Cars @mustang six exhausts are necessary
4. Give -1 Cars @mustang
5. Give Cars @mustang
6. Give 3 Cars @ford
7. Give 5 Cars @cobra_gt

The ones which should be successful ate 1,2,3,6,7

preg_match('/Give (\d+) Cars @(\w+)|GA (\d+) Cars @(\w+)/i', $a->text, $output);

print_r($output); produces:

```
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [0] => GA 5 Cars @mustang
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 5
    [4] => mustang
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [0] => Give 3 Cars @ford
    [1] => 3
    [2] => ford
)
Array
(
    [0] => Give 5 Cars @cobra_gt
    [1] => 5
    [2] => cobra_gt
)
```

As you can see it is not working with the lowercase ones, and for number #3 it doesn't produce the right array, it produces empty elements. Any idea where I am going wrong here?

Comment: Should only 1,2,3,6 and 7 be matched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the input:

1. give 4 cars
2. ga 5 cars
3. GA 5 Cars @mustang six exhausts are
   necessary
4. Give -1 Cars @mustang
5. Give Cars @mustang
6. Give 3 Cars @ford
7. Give 5 Cars @cobra_gt

And the expression:

```
/Give (\d+) Cars @(\w+)|GA (\d+) Cars @(\w+)/i
```

1. Does not match because you are only
   matching against something that has
   "`@something`" in it.
2. Same as #1
3. This matches as expected
4. The `-` in front of `1` causes the match to fail
5. There is no number between `Give` and `Cars`
6. This matches as expected
7. This matches as expected

As to why it doesn't produce the "right" array, it actually is.  In your expression you have 4 capture groups.  Just because your input matches the second of the OR'd expressions (the '`GA`' one) doesn't mean the group numbers start at 1, the groups will always have the same number, no matter how you match, so...

```
/Give (\d+) Cars @(\w+)|GA (\d+) Cars @(\w+)/i
      ^ 1         ^ 2      ^3          ^4
```

So if you match the '`Give`' case, you are going to have groups 1 and 2, and if you match the '`GA`' case, groups 3 and 4 will be filled.

(Also, the '`i`' modifier is working fine, you just aren't properly accounting for your inputs)

Answer (score 3):

1 and 2 are missing @
4 has -1 (this doesn't match \d)
5 is missing the number

you could change " @" to "( @)?" to make the @ optional.

Or:

```
preg_match('/(Give|GA) (-?\d+) Cars( @(\w+))?/i', $a->text, $output);
```

About the empty array elements, you have 4 submatches, even though they are seperated by an or (|), they all count, and only the ones used in your match will be populated.